# Regular expression in R. Capture specific field

Tags: regex, r

I have the following vector in R:

```
x <- c("id: capture this , something: the useless chunk , otherstuff: useless , more stuff")
```

And I want to get the string "capture this".
I have used this regular expression:

```
library(rex)
r <- rex(
  start,
  anything,
  "id: ",
  capture(anything),
  " , ", 
  anything
)
r
# > r
# > ^.*id: (.*) , .*
re_matches(x,r)
```

But what I got is:

```
> re_matches(x,r)
                                                                  1
1 capture this , something: the useless chunk , otherstuff: useless
```

It captures what I want but also the rest of the string. I just want the "capture this" field.
Even if I use the gsub function:

```
gsub("^.*id: (.*) , .*", "\\1", x)
```

using the same regular expression I got the same result.

This is the information of R:
*R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09) -- "Smooth Sidewalk"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)*

And the version of ubuntu:
*No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty*

Comment: Your "vector in R", named: r is a single string.  Where do functions "rex" and "re_matches" come from?

Comment: They come from the "rex" package. I use the rex function to build the "^.*id: (.*) , .* " expression and re_matches to get the result. I got the same result if I use: gsub("^.*id: (.*) , .*", "\\1", x)

Comment: Please provide complete self contained code examples.  The `library` call is missing.

Comment: You might find it useful to learn regular expressions well enough to avoid the need for the assistance provided by the "rex" package.  To me, (and others, I suspect) it is a bit of a barrier between the programmer and the problem.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, you're right. I'm currently using this package since I want to construct bigger regular expressions and make them readable for others. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you working with yaml? If so you might find the `yaml` package useful

```
x <- c("id: capture this , something: the useless chunk , otherstuff: useless , more: stuff")

yaml::yaml.load(gsub(' , ', '\n', x))$id
# [1] "capture this"
```

Note that I had to add a colon to get the above to work, but the nice thing about this solution is that you can extract each part based on a key field.

This next one is using your example string and doesn't use a package:

```
x <- c("id: capture this , something: the useless chunk , otherstuff: useless , more stuff")

gsub('id: (.*?) ,.*', '\\1', x)
# [1] "capture this"
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not necessarily need to use a package to grab the substring you're after. The next mistake with using `gsub` is your regular expression, `*` is a [**greedy**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) operator meaning it will match as much as it can and still allow the remainder of the regular expression to continue to match.

Use `*?` for a non-greedy match meaning "**zero or more — preferably as few as possible**".

```
gsub("^.*id: (.*?) , .*", "\\1", x)
                ^
```

If the string starts with "id", you can remove the anchor and initial `.*` token.

```
sub('id: (.*?) ,.*', '\\1', x)
# [1] "capture this"
```

**Note:** I used `sub` here instead since you have only one occurrence.

Comment: Thanks! I had that problem, I didn't know how to stop the * operator of matching the next similar patterns. And thanks for making clear the use of gsub and sub.

Answer (score 1):

```
    # using the rex package
    library(rex)
    x <- c("id: capture this , something: the useless chunk , otherstuff: useless , more stuff")
    r <- rex(start,"id: ",capture(non_puncts))
    re_matches(x,r)
    #1 capture this
```

Comment: I didn't know about the "no_puncts" shortcut and how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: non_puncts is in the "shortcuts" portion of the rex doc.  Note we pick up a trailing space by recognizing everything before the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a straight forward generalizable approach using the **qdapRegex** library I manage that can be used to grab "stuff" between a right and left boundary:

```
x <- c("id: capture this , something: the useless chunk , otherstuff: useless , more stuff")

library(qdapRegex)
rm_between(x, "id: ", " ,", extract=TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "capture this"
```